# aspx Form to XML File

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, forms

Basically what I am trying to is:

1. Catch a form submission;
2. Save it to an XML file;
3. Send it to another server.

My main issue is not being able to find much information about **XMLBuilder**. This following link looks like something I need, but I can only use XML Builder: [Creating a Contact form in Visual Studio ASPX and saving to an XML file when clicking SUBMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723850/creating-a-contact-form-in-visual-studio-aspx-and-saving-to-an-xml-file-when-clic)

My code is as follows:

**Default.aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="ToXMLApp.ToXMLForm" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="ToXMLForm" runat="server" defaultbutton="Submit">
    <div>
        <asp:Label runat="server">Firstname</asp:Label>&emsp;<asp:TextBox ID="Firstname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:Label runat="server">Surname</asp:Label>&emsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Submit_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Default.aspx.vb:**

```
Protected Sub Submit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    // XMLBuilder new xml file
    // save form results as xml fields
    // save xml file
    // send XML file (this is not as important atm)
    ToXMLForm.InnerHTML? // how do I retrieve inputs?

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know of an `XmlBuilder` class. Are you sure you have the name right?

Comment: Also, which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: I think the latest .NET, I downloaded Microsoft Visual Web Editor Express 2010.

Comment: What is this `XmlBuilder` you're talking about?

Comment: Ok, I see that the other post means System.Web.UI.WebControls.XmlBuilder. This is not a class to be used in your code. It's used by ASP.NET internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for the help, it was much appreciated. Here is the code that ended up working:

```
//Create the XDoc object
Dim XMLDoc As XDocument

XMLDoc = New XDocument(
    New XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
        New XElement("user",
            New XElement("details",
                New XElement("firstname", Firstname.Text),
                    New XElement("surname", Lastname.Text)
            )
        )
    )

    //Save test file
    XMLDoc.Save("C:\test.xml")
```

Answer (score 1):

I would parse the form and reconstruct using LINQ to XML. I know it doesn't sound like much help but you're probably better off getting pointed in that direction (XDocument, XElement, etc.) and working with those .NET datatypes in an object-oriented fashion versus relying on a specific implementation (like @John Saunders said, not really sure about XMLBuilder) to fulfill your business need. It really pays to work under the hood sometimes.

Comment: I noticed the XDocument type, will look into it more. Any idea how to access the form once it's posted/submitted though?

Comment: ASP.NET handles everything inside the form element differently than you might expect a regular form post using another technology. You can reference the form post, of course, but as a beginner, if I were you I'd focus on making each part of that form a specific asp.net control, which you can then reference from the codebehind. Set an ID for each of your elements explicitly (ID="FirstName") and then use that ID in your codebehind. You should be able to do something like string myFirstName = FirstName.Text in that case.

Comment: If you need more than that, I'd do it this way as a novice: use the OnClick event of the button you're using to submit to handle your XML document creation. Inside that OnClick handler, you'll want to create a new XDocument type, with the appropriate namespace, then create XElements with the values you want. Then add those XElements to your XDocument using the Add() method. It's extremely object-oriented and easy to use once you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void Submit_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   //Get the inputs
   var name = Firstname.Text;
   var surname = TextBox1.Text;

   //Now you transform the data as the example of the link you showed
   XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
   settings.Indent = true;
   settings.IndentChars = ("    ");

   var filepath = "data.xml";

   using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(filepath, settings))
   {
       // Write XML data.
       writer.WriteStartElement("data");
       writer.WriteElementString("name", name);
       writer.WriteElementString("surname", surname);
       writer.WriteEndElement();
       writer.Flush();
   }

   //Send XML file
   FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(FTPAddress + "/" + 
   Path.GetFileName(filePath));
   request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
   request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
   request.UsePassive = true;
   request.UseBinary = true;
   request.KeepAlive = false;

   FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(filePath);
   byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
   stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
   stream.Close();

   Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
   reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
   reqStream.Close();
}
```

Include the System.Net library.

I wrote in notepad, didn't compile it, so forgive if there's an error, but this is the path.